# Checksumming to verify rsync transfers

Tags: rsync, file-transfer, checksum

So rsync runs some checksums in the course of deciding what to transfer (i.e. what blocks within a file).  But is there any reason to trust the file you end up with on the receive side any more than you would for a normal network transfer?  Should I run checksums after rsync finishes to verify the data?  Is rerunning rsync with the pre-check (i.e. --checksum option) turned on an accepted way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the rsync checksum mechanism is fairly reliable.  The tradeoff here is the usual one: you can do more verification but it will take more time.  If you are really worried that a set of files most be exactly the same on two machines, you should run a separate verification.  For example, you can use md5sum on the file list on both sides and compare the results.  Assuming that the files don't change in the meantime (like log files) that will give you a very high confidence that the files are identical on both sides.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like rerunning with the pre-check (see above) is an okay way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync -Pahn --checksum /path/to/source /path/to/destination | sed '/\/$/d' | tee migration.txt`

`sed` removes directories from the checksum verification.
`tee` outputs to the screen and to the file at the same time.

Keep in mind that this might not be a suitable method if you have very large files, as the verification will take a long time.

[Source](https://techblog.jeppson.org/2014/10/verify-backup-integrity-with-rsync-sed-cat-and-tee/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your case, there is a special tool for monitoring the integrity of files after synchronization. It works independently of rsync and is completely open source of course.

https://github.com/dennisrazumovsky/precizer

precizer is a CLI application designed to check up the integrity of files after synchronization. The program recursively traverses directories and creates a database of files and their checksums, followed by a quick comparison.

precizer is focused on work with gigantic file systems. With the program it is possible to find synchronization errors by comparing data with files and their checksums from different sources. Or it can be used to crawling historical changes by comparing databases from the same sources over different times.

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE**

Assuming there are two hosts with large disks and identical contents mounted in /mnt1 and /mnt2 accordingly. The general task is to check whether the content is absolutely identical or whether there are differences.

1.Run the program on the first machine with host name, for example “host1”:

```
precizer --progress /mnt1
```

As a result of the program running all directories starting from /mnt1 will be recursively traversed and the host1.db database will be created in the current directory. The --progress option visualizes progress and will show the amount of space and the number of files being examined.

2.Run the program on a second machine with a host name, for example host2:

```
precizer --progress /mnt2
```

As a result, the host2.db database will be created in the current directory.

3.Copy the files with the host1.db and host2.db databases to one of the machines and run the program with the appropriate parameters to compare the databases:

```
precizer --compare host1.db host2.db
```

The following information will be displayed on the screen:

- Which files are missing on host1 but present on host2 and vice versa.
- For which files, present on both hosts, the checksums do NOT match.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).